# Partial derivative of loss function

Tags: partial-derivative, matrix-calculus

How I take the partial derivative with respect to $A_i$, B and $C_j$ from the following loss function:
$$ L=A_i^T B C_j $$
where $A_i$ and $C_j$ are vectors.(A, B and C are matrices).

Comment: Could you make more clarification? Also, are $A_i$ and $C_j$ vectors or matrices?

Comment: $A_i$  and  $C_j$ are vectors of A and C matrices, respectively.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure. But according to Eqs.(69) and (70) in "The matrix cookbook", I think that :

$$ \frac{∂(L)}{M}=U_iV_j^T  $$
$$ \frac{∂(L)}{U_i}=MV_j $$
$$ \frac{∂(L)}{V_i}=M^TU_j $$ .